# MAPI: How do I count the amount of folders in a mailbox

Tags: exchange-server, mapi

I've used MAPI on a project recently to traverse mailboxes and export them to .msg files so I know a bit but I would now like to efficiently count all the folders inside a mailbox. Can this be done with MAPI tables somehow? Is there a magic property for this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you only get the immediate child folders.
You can pass CONVENIENT_DEPTH flag to get all child folders returned. If I remember correctly, that will only work with the online Exchange stores (both mailbox and PF).

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I assume I can get to this with RDO also?

Comment: Yes, you can use RDOFolder.GetAllChildFolders in RDO.

Answer (score 1):

Open the message store using OpenMsgStore function and then open top of information store using HrOpenFolderEx and then use GetHierarchyTable to get the list of folders

Comment: IMAPIContainer::GetHierarchyTable I believe that is.

Comment: Yes...You can use that...Its gives you a table and then user HrQueryAllRows to get the list of folders.